# Error in raising a complex number to a power

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $z = \sqrt{6} + \sqrt{2}i.$

I  have determined that
$
z = 2\sqrt{2} e^\frac{\pi i}{6};
$
therefore $
z^4 = (2\sqrt2)^4 e^{\frac{2\pi }{3}i}\\=64e^{\frac{2\pi }{3}i}.$

However, my teacher wrote that $z^4=16\sqrt{2}\cdot e^{\frac{2\pi }{3}i}.$

I know that $z= \cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta) = e^{\theta i} $ and that $z^n = r^n \operatorname{cis}(n\theta);$ therefore $z^n=r^ne^{n\theta i}.$

How am I incorrect?

Comment: Their solution may be a typo, which happens.

Comment: You are right and your teacher is wrong.

Comment: Seems like your instructor did the $2^4$ bit but forgot the $\sqrt{2}$ part.